# NSData dataWithContentsOfFile vs NSInputStream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdata, nsxmlparser

I have to process XML, now using NSInputStream breaks my code as I have to rewrite lots of things.

**Will dataWithContentsOfFile entire file into memory, or only read contents requested for getBytes method?**

I am using NSData as input parameter to NSXMLParser, I wonder is there any documentation regarding this?

There is no documentation on apple's doc regarding internals of NSData's dataWithContentsOfFile or its implementation.

Comment: Please look this mail conversation http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/May/msg00765.html. Because you are more concern with binary processing look https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/BinaryData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000037i.

Comment: @SudeshKumar, please read the question, in none of the links you have provided mention anything about loading entire file into memory or not.

Comment: `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:...]` reads the entire file at once.

Comment: @HotLicks, I already looked upon documentation, no where its written that it reads the entire file at once or in parts.

Comment: I returns an NSData object containing the data.  How would it not read all of the file?

Comment: Somewhere in videos about iPhone optimization I had heard that NSData does not load entire file, instead it only loads the handle of file and it loads data from file when getbytes method is invoked and the requested range is loaded. I heard this nearly 2 years back, now I want to confirm this. And this behavior makes sense as well.

Comment: Are there any news, possibly some confirmation _how_ `dataWithContentsOfFile` is reading the bytes (for example using a memory mapped file approach) ?

Answer (score 0):

When you allocating NSData for NSXMALParser ,it means creating data buffer for that object and every object occupy memory (RAM) ,because iPhone IOS know very well how to use virtual memory. When you reading entire data from the file, it occupying object data and if  the data size is more than a few(depended upon OS algo) memory pages, the object uses virtual memory management. A data object can also wrap preexisting data, regardless of how the data was allocated. The object contains no information about the data itself (such as its type); the responsibility for deciding how to use the data lies with the client. In particular, it will not handle byte-order swapping when distributed between big-endian and little-endian machines.
I recommend you to read again this link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/BinaryData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000037i its related to iOS. But yes one thing concern with you ….in IOS there is type of owner of object. One is user and another one is IOS object. if you creating NSData that means you allocating memory buffer and assigning data pointer to this veriable, but at that moment entire data is resides inside memory. Its our assumption, but during this period IOS know how to handle this scenario. IOS uses vertual memory technique to handle data pages.